# How can I save my FormArray controls in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, formarray

I am used  contains FormArray to do something. And the component.ts is below:

```
export class AlumniInfoComponent implements OnInit{
    eduFormGroup: FormGroup;
    socialFormGroup: FormGroup;
    alumniActsFormGroup: FormGroup;

    education: FormArray = new FormArray([]);

    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private 
                alumniService: AlumniInfoService) {}

    ngOnInit() {

         this.eduFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
             name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
             birthPlace: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
             gender: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
             education: this.education,
          });   
      .....   
}
    addEducation() {

    (<FormArray>this.eduFormGroup.controls['education']).push(
        this._formBuilder.group({
        registrationTime: new FormControl(),
        graduationTime: new FormControl(),
        major: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        faculty: new FormControl(),
        educationBackground: new FormControl(),
        academicDegree: new FormControl(),
      })
    );
  }
```

}
and .html code is below:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper  #stepper>
     <mat-step [stepControl]="eduFormGroup">
         <form [formGroup]="eduFormGroup">
            <div>
                 <button mat-button class="circular ui icon button" 
                    (click)="addEducation()">
                     Add<mat-icon>add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
                 </button>
                  <ul class="list-group" formArrayName="education">
                     <div *ngFor="let education of 
                       eduFormGroup.controls['education'].controls; let 
                       i = index">
                          <div class="edu-class" formGroupName={{i}}>
                              <mat-form-field class="basic-info">
                                  <input
                                   matInput
                                   type="Date"
                                   formControlName="registrationTime"
                                   placeholder="registrationTime">

                              </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                   </ul>
            </div>
         </form>
     </mat-step>

</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

When I want to hit post api to server, how can I add entire FormArray controls to post method, I means how to iterate these controls inside FormArray in, for example saveEduFormData method which save the eduFormGroup data to server, method to save these data to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `this.eduFormGroup.controls['education'].value` contains what you need.